# Position iframe Overtop of Images/JS Loaded Images, Now iFrame is Under the Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, positioning

Having a problem, on my site I call a iframe using hidden in a DIV but when the iframe shows up the images of the site cover up the iframe.

I need a way to be able to position the iframe to the top of the page/overtop of the images that are currently blocking part of the iframe.

You can see my coding here on this domain:  www.SEO.mobi

To get access to see the iframe you need to on your keyboard enter:

↑↑↓↓←→←→BA↵

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your images in the slideshow has a z-index set.

```
<image style="z-index:6"/>

<image style="z-index:5"/>

<image style="z-index:4"/>

<image style="z-index:3"/>

<image style="z-index:2"/>

<image style="z-index:1"/>
```

Your pop-up div has `z-index:2` so the images with z-index above 2 will be positioned above the iframe.

```
<div id="popupContact">...</div>

#popupContact{
    z-index:2;
}
```

A quick fix would be to give the pop-up div a higher `z-index` than other elements.

Comment: louisbros you ROCK !!!  I missed that zindex on that area as was trying to use another zindex but was causing other problems, ah again you rock, thanks so much !!!